# Wordpress plugin how to call a function via a front end page form submit

Tags: wordpress, forms, function, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

i have a function in plugin that inserts values in database, i want this function to be called when i submit a form on the front end page. how would i do it ?

i have no idea what to do
this is the function i want to call now i don't know what else to do

```
function jal_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $welcome_name = 'Mr. WordPress';
    $welcome_text = 'Congratulations, you just completed the installation!';
    
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'dbquestions';
    
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 
            'name' => $welcome_name, 
            'text' => $welcome_text, 
        ) 
    );
}
```

i am not using a form on front end, rather i m using div classes, the class name is questions
this is the button on which i want to call that function

```
<input type="button" id='next' value="Next" onlick="sum_values()">
```

Comment: You can use ajax to call that function.

Comment: @GufranHasan how?? can u please elaborate it a little

Comment: okay wait just I am sharing some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try **JSON.stringify()** data before sending it to the AJAX as below:

```
function sum_values() {

var data = JSON.stringify({ 
    action: 'savedata', 
    'moneyOf': document.getElementById('priceSlider').value,
    'emailOf': document.getElementById('inputheaderBox').value
});

jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: data,               
        success: function(data){
            //alert('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

and write following code in **functions.php** file to save data into database:

```
<?php
  function savedata(){

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'table_name',
    array(
        'field1' => $_POST['moneyOf'],
        'field2' => $_POST['emailOf'],
    ),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
);

die();
return true;
}
//
add_action('wp_ajax_savedata', 'savedata'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_savedata', 'savedata'); 
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165664/discussion-on-answer-by-gufran-hasan-how-to-call-a-plugin-function-via-a-front-e).

Answer (score 0):

the above code needed a little bit of modification to call the function and it did heres the modified version

```
function abc(){


jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: { action: 'savedata', 'question_id': document.getElementById('question_id').value, 'text': document.getElementById('text').value },               
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the php function

```
function savedata(){
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('questoptions',
     array(
        'question_id' => $_POST['question_id'],
        'text' => $_POST['text']

),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
);

die();
return true;
}
```

it is calling the function now but the problem is that the database table is still empty